# get element id when scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, element

I have a website for read comic online.

HTML of read page is:

```
<div id="listimages">
<img src="abc1.jpg" id="image1" />
<img src="abc2.jpg" id="image2" />
<img src="abc3.jpg" id="image3" />
<img src="abc4.jpg" id="image4" />
</div>
```

I want to get the id of the image being scrolled to.
Example when I'm viewing img abc2.jpg I want get element id of it is #image2.

```
idnow = idnow_getted
```

Please help me, thanks everybody !

Comment: you want `ID` on `scrolled`? or on `hover`?

Comment: what if all images fit on one page and no scrolling is needed?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911138/jquery-trigger-function-when-element-is-in-viewport

Comment: jQuery Waypoints does just that: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the window's scrolltop and image's top position to get the id of the image which is scrolled to.

For ex,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
var $imgs = $('img');

$.each($imgs, function(item) {
    if($(item).position().top <= winTop)
         //get id here

});
});
```

Comment: all images ABOVE current viewport are "selected" too... not a real solution... see -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911138/jquery-trigger-function-when-element-is-in-viewport

Answer (score 0):

There may be two scenario in which you you want id of image and do further processing,

**First scenario** You want execute something on scroll of window.
In this case just add a handler on scroll event.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windowTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
        image = $('#listimages').find('img').filter(function(){
            return $(this).offset().top < windowTop+100;
           //i am adding 100 in windowTop as we can consider the the image as cuurent image even if it is little bit below than top of window.
        });


            //now you can directly use image if you want to manipulate it.
            //if you want id you can get it by
          var id=image[0].id //or image.attr('id'); 

    });
```

**Second scenario** , if you want to perform some action on trigger of any event.

```
function currentImg(){
            var windowTop = $(this).scrollTop(),
            image = $('#listimages').find('img').filter(function(){
                return $(this).offset().top < windowTop+100;
             });
           return image[0].id;

}
```

But remember adding events like scroll,mousemove are executed more often so they are suggested not to use much until you need it much .

Answer (score -2):

***Just Try with the following,***

**JavaScript and jQuery Part :**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#listimages img').mouseover(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML Part :**

```
<div id="listimages">
<img src="abc1.jpg" id="image1" />
<img src="abc2.jpg" id="image2" />
<img src="abc3.jpg" id="image3" />
<img src="abc4.jpg" id="image4" />
</div>
```

I think this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Mouseover isn't the same as scrolling.