# Run javascript function when div is scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, infinite

How do I run the onclick function when the div becomes visible by the user scrolling to it. Trying to set up infinite scrolling that loads automatically instead of users clicking this button.

The elements scroll horizontally inside another div.

```
<div id="bottom_end" class="next">
    <a onclick="load_more('/orderby/rising/page/12', '12', 'app_index')"></a>
    <p>Load more<br>in scroll</p>
</div>
```

Comment: **[Look This Question this will help you][1]**


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225102/jquery-event-to-trigger-action-when-a-div-is-made-visible

Comment: @MaulikAnand Note: You'll want to use the `[text](url)` format for [links in comments](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: @MaulikAnand thanks for that, however, I should have been more clear with "visible". I mean when it is in the viewport when the user scrolls to it

Comment: @MattEllwood For that, [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) (Read through the top 2 answers.) Also, [jquery trigger function when element is in viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911138/jquery-trigger-function-when-element-is-in-viewport).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using Jquery.

```
$( '#yourdiv').scroll(function() {
   if ( $(this)[0].scrollHeight - $(this).scrollTop() <= $(this).outerHeight()){
       //ajax method for getting your data
       //append response data to your div
    } 
});
```

Refer this for [How to implement ajax using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338016/capture-html-form-data-with-external-js-file/24338446#24338446)

Comment: Does this work for horizontal scrolling?

Comment: No, this works for vertical scrolling but you can put condition for horizontal as well. Logic will be same for infinite auto scroll. For that use scrollWidth and outerWidth. Refer this for 
[jquery-height-width-inner-and-outer](http://www.midnight-coding.com/2012/09/jquery-height-width-inner-and-outer.html)