# How to trigger this animation every time you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this animation on some headlines and would like it to run once only, but to be triggered on scroll, both up and down, every single time. As it is right now it runs only once or in an infinite loop.

```
$(function(){

    $("#slogan1").typed({
        strings: ["first string of text", "second string of text", "third string of text"],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 1500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: 'html', // or text
        // defaults to false for infinite loop
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });

    $(".reset").click(function(){
        $("#slogan1").typed('reset');
    });

});

function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
```

If it's of any relevance this animation is wrapped in a container with an animation that does exactly what I want, being triggered on scroll both ways as fallows:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('.slideright').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var imageHeight = $(this).height();
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + imageHeight && imagePos + imageHeight > topOfWindow) {
            $(this).addClass("slideRight");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("slideRight");
        }
    });
});
```

JavaScript is a foreign language to me so please provide your suggestion in context with the full code, otherwise I probably wont know what to do with it.
Thanks a lot for your help!

HTML

```
<div class="container element-to-hide slideright">
<h1>Some text<span id="slogan1"></span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post the related HTML as well.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I just added the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you are looking for:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("#slogan1").typed('reset');

    $("#slogan1").typed({
        strings: ["first string of text", "second string of text", "third string of text"],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        backDelay: 1500,
        loop: false,
        contentType: 'html', // or text
        // defaults to false for infinite loop
        loopCount: false,
        callback: function(){ foo(); },
        resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
    });
});

$(".reset").click(function(){
    $("#slogan1").typed('reset');
});

function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }

function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvL8gdwb/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and effort. I do see in your example that it does get triggered on scroll but only once. The idea would be to have it triggered every time it enters the viewport. I apologise if this wasn't clear enough in my question.

Comment: Hi Seamus, sorry to bother you again, you can see your script in action all over my project [**test page**](http://davidmartins.pt/tl/x2.htm). As you can see it is triggered every time you touch the mouse wheel which is bit annoying. Would it be possible to trigger the animation only once, every time it enters the viewport?

Comment: Check out this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911138/jquery-trigger-function-when-element-is-in-viewport  There is a jquery plugin you could use to trigger an action when an element enters the viewport. I have not used it before, but it looks promising.