# How to Stick the menu at the top when scrolling and also select the appropriate scroll section by highlighting the corresponding menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Was giving a try to fix the menu content to the top when the page scrolls and also when scrolling the particular scroll container link should get highlighted and the scrolling should be smooth which supports all the devices, without lagging.

Expected When I scroll to Link 2 data then the Link 2 menu tab should highlited ans also if i click on the link then also it should scroll to corresponding section.

Here it is what I tried:

[demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/hthfv72f/)

HTML:

```
<div class="header_part">Header Part</div>
<div class="section_stick">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#Link1">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link2">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link3">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Link4">Link4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="Link1">Link1 data</div>
<div id="Link2">Link2 data</div>
<div id="Link3">Link3 data</div>
<div id="Link4">Link4 data</div>
```

Please help me out with the changes and a sample demo.

Comment: Check this I think to get the value in scroll you need to use view port jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911138/jquery-trigger-function-when-element-is-in-viewport

Comment: You are selecting the class but not id. You should change `$(mySelector + "." + id)` to `$(mySelector + "#" + id)`;

Comment: ^ Also you can't use `$(...).position().top` directly. You need to store `$(...).position()` value in a var then use the `top` attr for that var.

Comment: Can any one help me out with the working demo from above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your js for scroll to the content section & highlight menu item  on scroll. You also need to change your css a bit.

**Updated JS**

```
var nav = $(".section_stick");
var stickyClass = "fixed_nav";
var headerHeight = $('.header_part').height();
var content = $('#Link1, #Link2, #Link3, #Link4');


$(window).scroll(function() {
    stickyMenuHandler();
    activeMenuHandler();
});


function activeMenuHandler(){
    content.each(function(){
        if(isElementInViewport($(this))){
            var _id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('.section_stick a').removeClass('is-active');
            $('.section_stick a[href="#' + _id +'"]').addClass('is-active');
        }
    });
}

function stickyMenuHandler(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight ) {
        nav.addClass(stickyClass);
    } else {
        nav.removeClass(stickyClass);
    }
};

nav.find('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetContent = $($(this).attr('href'));
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: targetContent.offset().top
    }, 500);
});

function isElementInViewport (el) {

    if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
        el = el[0];
    }
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
    );
}
```

[I also updated your demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmorshed/hthfv72f/1/)