# Javascript When Div is Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I would like the counter to only start counting once the div has been viewed. This will be lower down the page on a website so if it starts animating up it won't be seen by the visitor.

```js
$('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).text()
    }, {
        duration: 4000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.count{float: left}

.wording {float: left}

.spacer {height: 1000px; width: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wording">
Positive
Number: <br></div>

<span class="count">99</span><span class="percent">%</span>

<div class="spacer"> wait

</div>

<span class="count">99</span><span class="wording">%</span>
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery Waypoints plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5911243/5133030

Comment: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Thanks but I haven't been able to get these to work

Comment: @RyanReece Exactly what you want? What is your problem? Explain it.

Comment: Delay the animation of the numbers until they are in view.

Comment: Why you don't use longer time for duration?

Comment: Because it needs to start counting when it comes into view

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/n5ey0m23/ . Is it your purpose?

Comment: No it needs to start animation when it is in view

Comment: I don't understand. What is meaning of `start animation when it is in view`?

Comment: Well it's pointless for the numbers to animate from 0 to 99 if they're not on the screen. I need the visitor to scroll down to the div then then numbers being to animate/count up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `scroll` event to run counter when scroll position reached to counter element and it displayed in screen.

```js
var counterDone = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var elemPosTop = $(".count").position().top;
    var elemHeight = $(".count").height();
    var winScroTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    
    if (elemPosTop < winScroTop + winHeight - elemHeight)    
        counterDone = (counterDone == false) ? counter() : true;     
})
 
function counter(){
    $('.count').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 4000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```css
.spacer {
    height: 1000px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="spacer">Go to down</div>

<span>Counter: </span>
<span class="count">100</span>
<span class="percent">%</span>

<div class="spacer"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Your help here is massively appreciated. May I pay you for your time and effort